# Optimization - split a column of type set into multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I want to create new columns based on the elements of column `Col1`, which is of type `set`. Each element has a corresponding column name that is stored in a dict. Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)

N = 10**4 #number of rows in  the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({'Cnt': np.random.randint(2,10,N)})

# generate lists of random length
def f(x):
    return set(np.random.randint(101,120,x))
df['Col1'] = df['Cnt'].apply(f)

# dictionary with column names for each element in list
d = {'Item_1':101, 'Item_2':102, 'Item_3':103, 'Item_4':104, 'Item_5':105, 'Item_6':106, 'Item_7':107, 'Item_8':108, 
        'Item_9':109, 'Item_10':110, 'Item_11':111, 'Item_12':112, 'Item_13':113, 'Item_14':114, 'Item_15':115, 'Item_16':116, 
        'Item_17':117, 'Item_18':118, 'Item_19':119, 'Item_20':120}

def elem_in_set(x,e):
    return 1 if e in x else 0

def create_columns(input_data, d):
    df = input_data.copy()
    for k, v in d.items():
        df[k] = df.apply(lambda x: elem_in_set(x['Col1'], v), axis=1)
    return df

%timeit create_columns(df, d)
#5.05 s ± 78.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The problem is that the production dataframe has about 400k rows, and my solution does not scale well at all - I'm looking at around 10 minutes on my machine. The column containing all elements (`Col1`) could be type `list` instead of `set`, but that doesn't improve performance.
Is there a faster solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small change in your `create_columns` `apply`. Seems like it works much faster now.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)

N = 10**4 #number of rows in  the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({'Cnt': np.random.randint(2,10,N)})

# generate lists of random length
def f(x):
    return set(np.random.randint(101,120,x))
df['Col1'] = df['Cnt'].apply(f)

# dictionary with column names for each element in list
d = {'Item_1':101, 'Item_2':102, 'Item_3':103, 'Item_4':104, 'Item_5':105, 'Item_6':106, 'Item_7':107, 'Item_8':108, 
        'Item_9':109, 'Item_10':110, 'Item_11':111, 'Item_12':112, 'Item_13':113, 'Item_14':114, 'Item_15':115, 'Item_16':116, 
        'Item_17':117, 'Item_18':118, 'Item_19':119, 'Item_20':120}

def create_columns(input_data, d):
    df = input_data.copy()
    for k, v in d.items():
        df[k] = df.Col1.apply(lambda x: 1 if v in x else 0)
    return df

create_columns(df, d)
#191 ms ± 15.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```